# Path folder for linux pdf temp files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pdf, documents

After every time I open and read a PDF, I lose disk space (somewhere between 50mb and 800mb) , depending on the PDF size and how much I read from it.

Where does `Atril` save temporary files?

Answer (score 0):

#### Where does 'atril document viewer' save temporary files?

They are in `/tmp`, according to the discussion at [Tmp folder filling up - Support & Help Requests - Ubuntu MATE Community](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/tmp-folder-filling-up/9373).

In that thread someone has given the following explanation for the issue:

> When you open an epub file with `Atril`, it is unpacked into individual
>   files into a randomly named folder called `/tmp/atril-xxxx.`
>
> Note that if you close `Atril` and reopen the same file again, Atril
>   creates another folder in `/tmp` each time, with identical contents.
>
> Now for the thumbnailer: this one is triggered only if you open a
>   folder in `Caja` that is set to icon view.
>
> If you do, then each epub in that folder is unpacked into
>   `/tmp/atril-thumbnailer-xxxx`.

It appears to be a bug in `Atril`.